# kafka-python: how to check if broker list available in advance instead of showing error logs

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-python

My snippet looks like this, and the logic is if the brokers are available then the producer is not None.

```
     try:
        self.producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=broker_list)
     except kafka.errors.NoBrokersAvailable:
        self.producer = None
```

But, in this way, there will be a lot of logs printed if the brokers are not available. How can I avoid this?

```
2020-03-12 13:42:01 INFO <BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-1 host=device2:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('192.168.0.102', 9092)]>: connecting to device2:9092 [('192.168.0.102', 9092) IPv4]
2020-03-12 13:42:01 INFO Probing node bootstrap-1 broker version
2020-03-12 13:42:01 ERROR Connect attempt to <BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-1 host=device2:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('192.168.0.102', 9092)]> returned error 111. Disconnecting.
2020-03-12 13:42:01 INFO <BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-1 host=device2:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('192.168.0.102', 9092)]>: Closing connection. KafkaConnectionError: 111 ECONNREFUSED
2020-03-12 13:42:01 INFO <BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-1 host=device2:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('192.168.0.102', 9092)]>: connecting to device2:9092 [('192.168.0.102', 9092) IPv4]
2020-03-12 13:42:01 ERROR Connect attempt to <BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-1 host=device2:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('192.168.0.102', 9092)]> returned error 111. Disconnecting.
2020-03-12 13:42:01 INFO <BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-1 host=device2:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('192.168.0.102', 9092)]>: Closing connection. KafkaConnectionError: 111 ECONNREFUSED
2020-03-12 13:42:01 INFO <BrokerConnection node_id=bootstrap-0 host=device1:9092 <connecting> [IPv4 ('192.168.0.101', 9092)]>: connecting to device1:9092 [('192.168.0.101', 9092) IPv4]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really, brokers are considered unavailable if they cannot be reached and/or they do not respond to ApiVersions requests. So to check if servers are alive you'd need to establish a connection, send a request, and check if response returned is valid.

However, trivial checking whether *all* of the _bootstrap_servers_ are connectable might be sufficient - this way you could quickly eliminate e.g. firewall issues.

On the other hand, you might investigate logging levels for these classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use KazooClient to establish a connection with Zookeeper and then list the available brokers in the cluster.

Comment: Don't use Zookeeper anymore. Use the AdminClient